# Tree structure in minimax (python)

Tags: python, tree, minimax

I am trying to make AI for board game with minimax algorithm, but I have problem with creating a tree structure. I know that you actually don't need to build tree for minimax but I have to. I want to build Tree separately from minimax and then use minimax on that tree. I don't know how to do it so that is what I need help for. Thanks in advance.

So I tried this:

```
from queue import Queue


class TreeNode(object):
   __slots__ = 'parent', 'children', 'data', 'player'

def __init__(self, data, player):

    self.parent = None
    self.player = player
    self.children = []
    self.data = data

def is_root(self):

    return self.parent is None

def is_leaf(self):

    return len(self.children) == 0

def add_child(self, x):


    x.parent = self
    self.children.append(x)

def print_tree(self):
    print('  '*self.get_level() + '|--', end = '')
    print(self.data)
    if self.children:
        for each in self.children:
            each.print_tree()

def get_level(self):
    level = 0 
    p = self.parent
    while p :
        p = p.parent
        level += 1
    return level 


class Tree(object):
  def __init__(self):
      self.root = None
```

And I tried with recursion to create Tree. Board is Hash map representing state of board(initially is empty and it should be root, root children should be all possible moves on empty board and so on)

```
def make_tree(self,board, player, depth):

            
            list_possible_moves = self.possible_moves()
            last_move = []
            t = Tree()
            t.root = TreeNode(board,None)
            if depth > 0:
                node = TreeNode(board,player)
                board2 = deepcopy(self._board)
                player = player * -1
                for i in range(len(list_possible_moves)):
                    board2 = deepcopy(board2)
                    if len(last_move) != 0 :
                        board2.set_val(last_move[-1],"0")
                    if player == 1:
                        board2.set_val(i,"W")
                    else:
                        board2.set_val(i,"B")

                    child = TreeNode(board2,player)
                    if child.get_level == 1:
                        t.root.add_child()
                    else:
                        node.add_child(child)
                    if player == 1 :
                        self.make_tree(board2,1,depth-1)
                    if player == -1 :
                        self.make_tree(child,-1,depth-1)
            else :
                return None
```

But it is not working, and it takes 6-10 seconds to make tree.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to make a tree? Minimax itself "creates" the tree and goes through each branch to a specified depth.